# Web scraping/ Screen scraping

Tags: html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

In what all ways can we connect with bank sites for scraping the datas from that site? I have referred this site,
 https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/how-does-mint-com-connect-to-online-banks-in-order-to-get-or-download-transactio 
for knowing how mint.com is connecting to the banks. Yodlee was one of the option. Is there any other way to connect with the bank sites to get the account details of the specific user other than yodlee?

Comment: can anyone please answer me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other solutions but Yodlee has been the longest running provider for aggregation of financial data through both direct data access feeds from top banks as well as screenscrape solutions to cover smaller FI's.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [cashedge](https://www.fiserv.com/about/brands/cashedge.aspx)
and also this [Post](http://www.quora.com/What-is-a-bank-account-aggregation-API-like-Yodlee-that-is-reasonably-priced-for-startups)